# how to add output using do while loops?

Tags: java, output

I need to add all the costs of the beverages until 5 is entered to quit the program. How do I go about doing that? When I run this program it only shows the total of the last order and not all of the orders.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Beverage
{
  // Constants
  static final double COSTOFCOFFEE = 1.00;
  static final double COSTOFTEA = .75;
  static final double   COSTOFCHOCOLATE = 1.25;
  static final double  COSTOFCAPPUCCINO = 2.25;
  static final double tax = 0.06;

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  // This method determines the type & amount of beverages desired
  {
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    double cost = 0;           // cost of the beverages
    int numberOfCups = 0;      // number of cups desired
    int bevType;                // type of beverage selected
    double totalcost = 0 ; 
    do
    {
      System.out.println("Hot Beverage Menu");
      System.out.println("Please select a choice from the following");
      System.out.println("1:  Coffee");
      System.out.println("2:  Tea");
      System.out.println("3:  Hot Chocolate");
      System.out.println("4:  Cappuccino");
      System.out.println("5:  EXIT ");
      bevType = keyboard.nextInt();
      if (bevType < 5 && bevType > 0 )
      {
        System.out.println("How many cups would you like?");
        numberOfCups = keyboard.nextInt();
      }
      switch(bevType)
      {
        case 1 : cost = numberOfCups * COSTOFCOFFEE;
          break;
        case 2 : cost = numberOfCups * COSTOFTEA; 
          break;
        case 3 : cost = numberOfCups* COSTOFCHOCOLATE;
          break;
        case 4 : cost = numberOfCups * COSTOFCAPPUCCINO;    
          break;
        case 5 :  System.out.println("Thanks for your order");
          totalcost = totalcost + cost;
          break;
        default : System.out.println("Invalid Selection");          
      }    
      if (bevType == 1 || bevType == 2 || bevType == 3 || bevType == 4)
        System.out.printf("The total cost is $%.2f \n" , cost);
    }while (bevType!=5);
    if(bevType == 5)
      System.out.println("The total cost of all beverages is " +totalcost);
    keyboard.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: please format this better and remove extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Add each `cost` to `totalcost`. Something like,

```
if (bevType == 1 || bevType == 2 || bevType == 3 || bevType == 4)
     System.out.printf("The total cost is $%.2f \n" , cost);
     totalcost += cost; //<-- add to total.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is only showing you the last value is because you're re-assigning your "cost" variable without keeping track of it. In your switch you're saying:

```
cost = numberOfCups * X //where X is whatever type of coffee
```

The next time someone selects something that isn't 5 you lose the value of cost by saying cost =.

There are two ways to go about fixing this issue. The first is to use a formula that allows cost to maintain its value throughout. This would be done by saying

```
cost = cost + (numberOfCups) * X
```

However, that confuses the term "cost", since we are talking about the cost of the item, not the total cost. However, you already have a variable that can keep track of the total cost throughout "totalCost".

So inside your if statement after your switch you could add

```
totalCost = totalCost + cost;
```

or, using a cleaner way to write it;

```
totalCost += cost;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line  "totalcost = totalcost + cost;" under case 5 and

add "totalcost += cost;" under if condition

```
 case 5 :  System.out.println("Thanks for your order");
           // totalcost = totalcost + cost; <-----remove this line
           break;

 default : System.out.println("Invalid Selection");          
}    

if (bevType == 1 || bevType == 2 || bevType == 3 || bevType == 4)
{  System.out.printf("The total cost is $%.2f \n" , cost);
   totalcost += cost; 
}
```